# not able to upload xlsx or docx file in laravel 5.7

Tags: excel-2010, excel-2007, laravel-5.7

Hi I'm trying to upload a xlsx file to the laravel api, (I am able to upload (images, xls) files), but I'm not able to do so I am getting the below details as follows

request my header has Content-Type as multipart/form-data
[image]

response for the `$file = request()->file('user_bulk_upload'); var_dump($file);`

```
 object(Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)[424]
 private 'test' (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile) =>                                              boolean false
 private 'originalName' (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile) => string 'sudo1.xlsx' (length=10)
private 'mimeType' (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile) => string 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' (length=65)
private 'error' (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile) => int 0
protected 'hashName' => string 'jFWNUFGJVuAMNi8p9BdzuZmKXu2MA5RtiOpopBPO' (length=40)
private 'pathName' (SplFileInfo) => string 'C:\xampp\tmp\php2472.tmp' (length=24)
private 'fileName' (SplFileInfo) => string 'php2472.tmp' (length=11)
```

and for `$path = $file->store('excel', 'public');var_dump($path);`

I'm getting response as

```
'excel/jFWNUFGJVuAMNi8p9BdzuZmKXu2MA5RtiOpopBPO.bin' (length=50)
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem with this function bellow used for multiple uploads:

```
public static function uploadFiles(int $ticketId, array $files)
{
  $dir = self::documentsDir($ticketId);

  /** @var Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile $file */
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fileName = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Ymd')."-".strtotime(\Carbon\Carbon::now()).".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file->storeAs($dir, $fileName, ['disk' => 'public']);
  }
 }
```